# ffmpeg concatenate 3 videos with crossfade

Tags: ffmpeg

Im trying to join 3 videos together with a crossfade effect.

I can get this working for 2 videos (sourced from stackoverflow but cant find the link):

```
ffmpeg -y -i part1.mp4 -i part2.mp4 -f lavfi -i color=black:s=1920x1080 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=out:st=10:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[va0]; \
 [1:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+10/TB[va1]; \
 [2:v]trim=duration=20[over]; \
 [over][va0]overlay[over1]; \
 [over1][va1]overlay=format=yuv420[outv]" \
-vcodec libx264 -map [outv] merged.mp4
```

But cant work out how to make this work for 3 videos.

I don't need any audio. Any ideas?

Cheers,

Comment: Do you want fade-out and then fade-in or crossfade between the videos?

Comment: looking to crossfade, cheers

Comment: Did you get the original code from here? https://superuser.com/questions/778762/crossfade-between-2-videos-using-ffmpeg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ffmpeg-concat](https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/ffmpeg-concat) is the easiest way to accomplish what you want and allows you to use a bunch of sexy OpenGL transitions, with the default being crossfade.

```
ffmpeg-concat 0.mp4 1.mp4 2.mp4 -o out.mp4
```

[ffmpeg-gl-transition](https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/ffmpeg-gl-transition) is a more complicated custom ffmpeg filter which allows you to use GLSL to smoothly transition between two video streams. This filter is significantly easier to use and customize than the alternatives listed here.

```
./ffmpeg -i 0.mp4 -i 1.mp4 -filter_complex "gltransition=duration=4:offset=1.5" out.mp4
```

Comment: ffmpeg-concat is currently not working with clips that contains video+audio.

Comment: @fish2,Test like ffmpeg-concat 0a.mp4 0a.mp4 -o out.mp4 (clip files provides in your github repository) produced a freezed video in the last few seconds.

Comment: if your version of ffmpeg doesn't have `gltransition` you can use `xfade`

Answer (score 4):

ok so im not sure if this is the best way to do this but i got it working:

```
ffmpeg -y -i part1.mp4 -i part2.mp4  -i part3.mp4 -f lavfi -i color=black:s=1920x1080 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=out:st=10:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; \
 [1:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=10:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+10/TB[v1]; \
 [2:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=10:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+20/TB[v2]; \
 [3:v]trim=duration=30[over]; \
 [over][v0]overlay[over1]; \
 [over1][v1]overlay[over2]; \
 [over2][v2]overlay=format=yuv420[outv]" \
-vcodec libx264 -map [outv] merge.mp4
```

Comment: may I please know what's outv? thanks

Comment: its just a variable you assign to the latest output and then he maps it to the actual file name [outv] -> -map [outv] merge.mp4