# Use ffmpeg to sequentially add multiple audio tracks and pin a specific track to the end

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have a single video with no audio tracks and want to add several audio tracks sequentially (each track starts immediately after the other).

The basic case might look something like this:

```
|-----------VIDEO-----------VIDEO-------------VIDEO-----------VIDEO-----------|  
|---FULL AUDIO TRACK 1---|---FULL AUDIO TRACK 2---|---PARTIAL AUDIO TRACK 3---|
```

Here is my attempt to achieve this:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mov -i audio1.mp3 -i audio2.mp3 -i audio3.mp3 -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -map 2:0 -map 3:0 out.mp4
```

Of course it doesn't produced the desired result. It only uses the first music clip in out.mp4, and no other audio tracks are started when it ends.

**Question 1**
What am I missing in order to add multiple audio tracks sequentially? I assume it's specifying starting and end points of audio clips but I'm coming up short on locating the syntax.

...

In addition, I'm looking for a way to ensure that the video ends with the full duration of AUDIO TRACK 3, as seen below:

```
|-----------VIDEO-----------VIDEO-------------VIDEO-----------VIDEO-----------|  
|---FULL AUDIO TRACK 1---|---PARTIAL AUDIO TRACK 2---|---FULL AUDIO TRACK 3---|
```

In this case, AUDIO TRACK 2 gets trimmed so that the full AUDIO TRACK 3 is pinned to the end.

**Question 2**
Can this type of audio pinning be done in FFmpeg, or would I have to trim AUDIO TRACK 2 with another program first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the atrim, asetpts, and concat filters:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mov -i audio1.mp3 -i audio2.mp3 -i audio3.mp3
  -filter_complex "[2:a]atrim=duration=5,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a2];[1:a][a2][3:a]concat=n=3:a=1:v=0[a]"
  -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c copy -c:a aac -shortest output.mp4
```

- [atrim](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#atrim) trims the audio. You can also use the `start` and/or `end` options if you prefer them over `duration`.
- [asetpts](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts_002c-asetpts) resets the timestamps (required by concat).
- [concat](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat) concatenates each audio segment.

If you want to automate this you'll have to script it. You can get the duration of each input with `ffprobe`:

```
ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 input.mp4
```

Then use that to determine the duration of whatever audio stream you want to trim.

Comment: perfect. I picked up on your direction for calculating duration - but not all will. I would add the simple calculation for the duration, maybe with a note to use it when replacing ''duration=5'. For example, duration = audio2.mp3(D) = video.mov(D) - audio3.mp3(D) - audio1.mp3(D), where (D) is duration for each named file.

Comment: do you have any direction for adding multiple video sources to this script with a 1 second cross fade between them?

Comment: @kraftydevil See [these](https://superuser.com/a/834035/110524) [three](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41580680/1109017) [answers](https://superuser.com/a/1350872/110524).